# AngularJS variable value in location.href in onclick is not resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In HTML i have a angular variable called

> boards.current.url

whose value i can see via

#### {{boards.current.url}}

However i want to use it's value in location.href as below,

```
<div class="board" onclick="location.href='{{boards.current.url}}'" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

this is not working - the value of angular variable

> boards.current.url

doesn't get resolved - any insights?

Answer (score 1):

use angular-directive **`ng-click`** instead of **`onclick`**

```
<div class="board" ng-click="location.href='{{boards.current.url}}'" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write it is to make use of ng-href :

```
<div class="board" ng-href="{{boards.current.url}}" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref